# Make a full terminal window application like Vim/Mutt/Cmus

Tags: python, terminal

I'm not sure quite how to word this, which is probably why I'm having trouble finding an answer.

I have a command line script that runs a rummy game, I want it to take over the terminal kind of like how Vim or Mutt does, so that each round is refreshed in the full terminal window rather than just printing out row after row of text.

Can someone tell me what that is called, so I can research it and find out how to do it?

Repo: https://github.com/sarcoma/Cards

Comment: A GUI application (Graphical User Interface) - look at tkinter in the python standard library.

Comment: Doesn't that open a GTK window? I mean that it would run in the terminal sort of how Vim does.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque a GUI does not run in the console, i believe that Sarcoma is after a curses style interface

Comment: Maybe, who knows?

Comment: i believe that pythons curses module does what you require, at least on non windows platforms https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html with the console module working on windows: http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm but looks like thats not very well supported (up to xp?) may work on newer platforms

Comment: @JamesKent Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment "pythons curses module does what you require".

This is what you need to take over the terminal: https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a console user interface. One of the best libraries for python would be http://urwid.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, looks interesting. I like to make things difficult for myself so I'll likely stick with Curses, got some basic user interaction going need to write some classes to wrap it up.